# Left justify 9.2 SQL select SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, decimal

My question is fairly straight forward. I am querying a value in SQL that is stored as 929.77 but I need the column to always to be 11 digits even it they are all zeros so I want to pull the value so it displays as 00000092977. Right now I have the the exact opposite and is pulling 92977000000.

Thanks in advance.

```
LEFT(REPLACE(Cast(ISNULL(c2.preinjwage,0) as varchar), '.', '') + '0000000000',11) as 'wage'
```

Comment: Well...if the 0's are on the wrong side have you tried switching them to the other side and using RIGHT instead???

Answer (score 2):

The opposite:

```
RIGHT('0000000000'+REPLACE(Cast(ISNULL(c2.preinjwage,0) as varchar(12)), '.', ''),11) as 'wage'
```

---

Quick test:

```
declare @in decimal(9,2)='929.77'

select right('0000000000'+replace(Cast(isnull(@in,0) as varchar(12)), '.', ''),11) as 'wage'
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/GTGSJ72810

returns:

```
+-------------+
|    wage     |
+-------------+
| 00000092977 |
+-------------+
```

Comment: Perfect!  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you always have two digits after the decimal (as if the number of digits after the decimal can vary the proposed format doesn't make sense as it won't distinguish between 1.11 and 111)

You can also use

```
SELECT FORMAT(CAST(ISNULL(c2.preinjwage,0) * 100 AS INT), 'd11')
```